# Aggregate dataset by key and list the rest of values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to achieve aggregation by key and getting the list as aggregation.Not sure if i am able to explain.I am new to these spark features.

```
case class myScheme(classId: Int,
                        StudentId: Long,
                        joiningDate: java.sql.Timestamp,
                        SchoolName: String
                       )

println( myDS)

 classId | studentId| joiningDate |SchoolName
    1|100|2010-01-01|"School1"
    2|110|2011-01-01|"School1"
    2|200|2010-01-01|"School1"
    3|300|2020-02-02|"School2"
```

I want to group all student Ids by schoolName and classId.

The final result from the above dataset:

```
"school1" ,1, [100 ]
"school2" ,2, [110,200] 
"school3" ,3, [300]
```

Comment: I'm afraid that you're not going to be able to do it with that fuction. Documentation states that it accepts function `(V, V) => V`, which basically means the output type has to be the same as the type of two elements you provide as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is already available in form of a (typed) dataset, you can use `groupByKey` to stay within the typed API:

```scala
//input data
val ds: Dataset[myScheme] = ...

//case class for the result
case class Group(SchoolName: String,
                 classId: Int,
                 data: List[myScheme])

//the grouping operation
val dsGrouped: Dataset[Group] =
  ds.groupByKey(r=> (r.SchoolName, r.classId))
    .mapGroups((key, values) => Group(key._1, key._2, values.toList))

dsGrouped.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|SchoolName|classId|data                                                                            |
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|School1   |1      |[{1, 100, 2010-01-01 00:00:00, School1}]                                        |
|School2   |3      |[{3, 300, 2020-02-02 00:00:00, School2}]                                        |
|School1   |2      |[{2, 110, 2011-01-01 00:00:00, School1}, {2, 200, 2001-01-01 00:00:00, School1}]|
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks . excellent solution

Comment: In this code, if i need to just select studentId to make List.how do i achieve that. Becuase in values we have the whole dataset row.

Comment: @CoolGoose change the definition of the `Group` case class and replace the `data` field with a Long for the Id. In the `mapGroups` function, map the `values`  iterator to a list of the the student ids. However, if you just need the IDs Grishas answer is better.

Comment: How do i access the studentId from values iterator.

Comment: @CoolGoose instead of using `values.toList` use `values.map(_.StudentId).toList` to map each element of the iterator to the StudentId before creating the list

Comment: Werner, if i need to use grouped here  "  values.map(_.StudentId).toList "  to spill over  another list  , how do i use?

Comment: @CoolGoose  not sure if I understand your last comment correctly. What would be the expected result?

Comment: No problems. Thanks for checking .

Answer (score 3):

Your current input and expected result do not make much sense, but it seems that you need a simple `groupBy` with `collect_list`:

```
myDS.groupBy("SchoolName", "classId").agg(collect_list("studentId")).show 

+----------+-------+-----------------------+
|SchoolName|classId|collect_list(studentId)|
+----------+-------+-----------------------+
|   School1|      1|                  [100]|
|   School2|      3|                  [300]|
|   School1|      2|             [110, 200]|
+----------+-------+-----------------------+
```